# How do I create / use a travel-able spline?

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, spline

I'm creating a system in which a player character travels along a defined spline path.  Here is what I need to do:

1. Input an array of Vector3 (XYZ) coordinates.
2. Generate spline data from those Vector3s.
3. Return a Vector3 for a given relative distance along the spline (0.0 - 1.0)

I'm using a provided library from [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Hermite_Spline_Controller) which sort of does what I need, but it the resulting spline has a tendency to "slingshot" around control points by slowing down around curves and speeding up in straightaways.  It seems like a natural side-effect of spline interpolation.

Unfortunately, my character needs to travel at a constant speed, and I need a way to derive this.

Is there a good library in C# (or C++ which I can convert) that I can use?

Failing that, is there a decent reference on how spline math works from which I can learn?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "slowing down around curves and speeding up in straightaways" - a spline does not have any concept of speed on its own, and speed usually means distance/time - that should not have to change regardless of the form of the spline, or?

Comment: What you're looking for is how to [reparameterize your spline](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~kearney/pubs/CurvesAndSurfacesArcLength.pdf) using something like arc length.  If you're more a paper book guy, Computer Animation: Algorithms and Techniques chapter 3 is a good resource. The intro. in the pdf I linked should give you enough terms to find better resources.

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking through several resources and this looks like it will help greatly.

Comment: Do you have points to go through, and control points too ? (Does [how-to-create-a-cubic-bezier-curve-when-given-n-points-in-3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526940/how-to-create-a-cubic-bezier-curve-when-given-n-points-in-3d) help at all ?)

Comment: @TomMurray You can [see my implementation](https://github.com/Jerdak/FreeFormDeformation/blob/master/FreeFormDeformation/tyrPather.cpp) of a reparam'd pathing spline.  I don't know useful the code is as it lacks comments.  But it might be that little bit that gets you the rest of the way.